# Glide clear() method can't be resolved

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to fix `OutOfMemoryException`'s in my Android app, in my recyclerView I want to write:

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(final ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    Glide.clear(viewHolder.getImageView());
}
```

But I get the error:

> error: cannot find symbol method clear(ImageView)

I am using:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

Comment: use `Glide.with(viewholder.itemView.getContext()).clear(viewHolder.getImageView());` - this may not solve the OOM's though, but is correct syntax for clearing  the image.

Comment: @MarkKeen You should submit your comment as an answer so OP can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

according to the [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/420/com/bumptech/glide/RequestManager.html#clear-android.view.View-) for `clear` method.

```
/**
   * Cancel any pending loads Glide may have for the view and free any resources that may have been
   * loaded for the view.
   *
   * <p> Note that this will only work if {@link View#setTag(Object)} is not called on this view
   * outside of Glide. </p>
   *
   * @param view The view to cancel loads and free resources for.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if an object other than Glide's metadata is put as the view's
   *                                  tag.
   * @see #clear(Target)
   */
  public void clear(@NonNull View view) {
    clear(new ClearTarget(view));
  }
```

therefor your `OutOfMemoryException` will be handeled by clear method.

and change your code a little , pass context to Glide :

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.getImageView().getContext()).clear(viewHolder.getImageView());
```